# Django view that rewrites URL to contain username as a query parameter?

Tags: django, url, django-views, url-rewriting, analytics

I want to do simple analytics over which user is doing what on my Django site.

I think the simplest way is to rewrite all URLs so that they contain "?username=foo".

This will only happen on GET urls that don't already have any URL query parameters.

How do I do this? Can I rewrite the URL to include a new query parameter from a view?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to add a get parameter to each view while the request already contains the user? Also you should probably use the [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) layer to log user actions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would have to change anything except the templates for this.

If your existing url like `http://server/myapp/view1` then accessing an url like this `http://server/myapp/view1?username=foo` will also work.

So your existing views will work as is.

However, you will have to change templates that renders the links as per new scheme. For example for above view if you are doing `{% url 'view1' %}` to get a link, then you will have to change it to `{% url 'view1'%}?username={{user}}`.

Comment: This makes no sense at all, there's already a user in the request as per my answer was made clear, also doing this kind of logging in each view is boilerplate

Comment: @Hedde yours is another approach and this is another approach.